# Redoing a extra merge and a accidental contribution from the wrong user

Tags: git, merge

I have the following git history that I would like to sort out a bit:

[image: Git History]

The issue occurred by using a remote editor fixed to a different git account but that had permissions for mine. Thus there are two contributors but they are both me. I then tried to fix that issue and got the red and black overlap looking commit instead. Then somehow I managed to pull and do a merge duplicating the results with a merge (the actual merge). The merge says that no changes occurred. Is there anyway I can clean this up and reassign credit just to black user not red user? I'm sure I'm skipping over details but I am not sure what else is relevant. Thanks!

Comment: I hope your question easy to understand, then your problem will be resolved soon.